# Android apps stopped eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, android-fragments, android-intent, android-asynctask

Why do I get this error when start my android app?

```
07-21 22:27:41.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1803): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-21 22:27:41.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1803): Process: com.example.viadroid, PID: 1803
07-21 22:27:41.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1803): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.viadroid/com.example.viadroid.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-21 22:27:41.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
07-21 22:27:41.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
07-21 22:27:41.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-21 22:27:41.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-21 22:27:41.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-21 22:27:41.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-21 22:27:41.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
07-21 22:27:41.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-21 22:27:41.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-21 22:27:41.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-21 22:27:41.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-21 22:27:41.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-21 22:27:41.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1803): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-21 22:27:41.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     at com.example.viadroid.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
07-21 22:27:41.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-21 22:27:41.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-21 22:27:41.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
07-21 22:27:41.570: E/AndroidRuntime(1803):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: You need to post some code otherwise I can't help you with your issue. From the looks of it, you seem to have a nullpointerexception at com.example.viadroid.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30

Comment: Exception Only without code will not solve your problem. please read SOF help guide on how to ask a good question.

Comment: I have always felt NPE are the most easiest one to solve